# Write session start on 1 page or all pages?

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

All the tutorials say to put session start.  They don't say if that should be in all pages on the website, or some, or only 1.

And if it's only 1 page, does it have to be the main page?  Or a page with a form that I am making that puts the session ID in the database?  If the visitor never visits a page with a session id but they are on the site, do they still have a session id?

Answer (score 25):

You need to put this in each page that need to access the session data before accessing (or creating) any session data.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: So I would put session start at the top of each page on the website, AND I would put it in the code that will put the session ID in the mysql database?  So session start should be written 2 times on those pages?

Comment: No. You only need it once per page but before accessing the data.

Answer (score 25):

Just for a matter of completeness you can choose to write `session_start();` in all pages, in just one or in none of them. Let me explain this.

You need to start session in every script where you need access to `$_SESSION` variable but instead of putting `session_start();` in every single script you can create a file headers.php and put there all your repetitive code including `session_start();`

If everything in your application needs access to `$_SESSION` you can forget the use of `session_start();` simply setting `session.auto_start = 1` in your php.ini file. You will be able to access `$_SESSION` without writing `session_start();` before.

[More here](http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/automatically-start-session-on-every-page-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is going to access Session variables needs to start the session.

So unless you have a php page that is non-dependent on the session than every page needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare session_start(); in every page if you want to get data from $_SESSION or store data into $_SESSION in those particular page. If you do not need to interact with $_SESSION then you don't have to declare session_start().@hmwhat